# Combine/Merge rows with missing data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would prefer something with `data.table`, `tidyr`, or `dplyr` as I have a quite large dataset.
About the data, I have a dataset like the one below:

```
GVar1     Stop1   Stop2   Stop3   Stop4   (...)
   1        A      NA      NA      NA     (...)
   1        NA     B       D       NA     (...)
   2        D      J       E       NA     (...)
   3        F      NA      NA      NA     (...)
   3        NA     B       NA      NA     (...)
   3        NA     NA      C       NA     (...)
   3        NA     NA      NA      J      (...)
```

Please mind that there are more than 4 Stop columns, and that they can vary depending on the dataset. However they are always called Stop followed by a number.
The idea is to merge by `GVar1` and all the columns to end up with something like this:

```
GVar1     Stop1   Stop2   Stop3   Stop4   (...)
   1        A      B       D      NA     (...)
   2        D      J       E       NA     (...)
   3        F      B       C       J      (...)
```

I've tried so far `summarise` from `dplyr`, `DT[.,]` from `data.table` and a couple of other options but nothing really worked.
I have the feeling that I should be using `dplyr`'s `if_else` but so far I couldn't end up with the result I wanted as I have quite some unspecified columns.

Comment: Like `DT[,lapply(.SD,na.omit),GVar1]`?

Comment: @lukeA, I had to replace `GVar1` by `"GVar1"`, but then I get an error `Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'`. It also seems incredibly slow with the `lapply` as I'm working with about 9 million observations.

Comment: If possible, provide an example that reproduces the error and that also demonstrates performance issues.

Comment: @lukeA regarding the error, it was fixed after converting it again to data.table. So I guess it was on my side.
About the performance, it takes 288.349 seconds for 9 Million results, which based on other functions I have, seems slow. Most operations even `summarising`, never take longer than 10 seconds.
But I've seen such slow speeds before with `lapply`, so I wonder if there's an alternative to it.
I wanted to provide an example but I can't post here 9 million results with 22 variables. So the example above is the maximum I can do.

Comment: `lapply´ just picks the columns. I'm sorry, but it's - at least for me - hardly possible to give suggestions based on what is known about your data. However, I'm by far no data table expert or anything either. So... maybe other folks have suggestions.